# Electronic devices - probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have two electronic devices $1$ and $2$. The life expectancy of each device is is $X_1$ and $X_2$, and:
\begin{align}
f_{X_1} &= \begin{cases} ax, 50 \leq x \leq 60 \\ 0, \text{ else} \end{cases} \\
f_{X_2} &= \begin{cases} \frac{1}{10}, 50 \leq x \leq 60 \\ 0, \text{ else} \end{cases}
\end{align}

$a$ is a parameter. 
I have a system and those devices are connected in a series. What is the probability that the system will collapse after less than 51.19 minutes given that the two devices collapsed after less than 52 minutes?

So I'm not sure how to begin even. First, I can say that this is PDF so I need to do an integral to get to the CDF? and then to sum up since the devices are connected in a row? And still, how can solve for the parameter a?

Comment: The first thing to point out is that I don't think $a$ is a parameter per se, but rather it is something which is initially unknown. You can work out what $a$ is by remembering that the probability density function $f_{X_1}$ must integrate to 1.

Comment: When you say the electronic devices are connected in a row... does that mean 'in series'?? Are we meant to use our knowledge of electronics to understand that if one device fails, then system collapse??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all calculate the parameter $a$ of $X_1$ rv. It is very easy to calculate as

$$\int_{50}^{60}f(t)dt=1 \rightarrow a=\frac{1}{550}$$

Then, remember that if the two devices are connected in a series, the system collapse when the first of the two devices collapse. So you have to set the following probability

$\mathbb{P}[min(X_1;X_2)<51.19|X_1<52;X_2<52]$

That is equivalent to calculate

$$1-\frac{[F_{X_1}(52)-F_{X_1}(51.19)][F_{X_2}(52)-F_{X_2}(51.19)]}{F_{X_1}(52)F_{X_2}(52)}$$

Where F is the CDF of the distribution. In numbers, we have

$$1-\frac{[\frac{52-50}{10}-\frac{51.19-50}{10}][\frac{52^2-50^2}{1100}-\frac{51.19^2-50^2}{1100}]}{\frac{52-50}{10}\cdot\frac{52^2-50^2}{1100}}\approx 83.4 \%$$

Comment: Thanks! So What I need to basically do is Integer of the first device and the second one (from 50 to 52), and then to multiply them (since they are independent)? and then another integer from 50 to 51.19

Comment: @JustEquvilant : no, I updated my answer with more hints

Comment: Thank you! So I solved this and got 0.0196. I did integrals for the relevant functions from 50-52 and 50-51.9. for $X1$ I used $X^2/2$ (and got a out of the brackets) and for $X2$ I did X and got $1/10$ out of the brackets.

Comment: @JustEquvilant :   I do not agree. See my calculation above

Comment: Thanks! but if you don't mind I have a questions, since what's given was a density probability function, shouldn't I "transform" this to cumulative probability? making $x$ to $x^2$ (for $x1$) in the numerator. that's what got me confused

Comment: Yes of course. If you look well at my solution I based it just on the CDF's (that I have already calculated)